# Plot of frequencies with counts in R

Tags: r, plot

The frequency plot that I'm trying to do is

- Barplot with counts above each bar
- Relative frequency in left side
- Cumulative frequency in right side

The dataset is

```
dput(x2)
c(1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L)
```

The distribution of frequencies are

```
table(x2)
x2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
4 8 8 5 8 3 2
```

The relative frequencies are

```
prop.table(table(x2))
x2
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
0.10526316 0.21052632 0.21052632 0.13157895 0.21052632 0.07894737 0.05263158
```

EDIT: Like in the image below, but with cumulative frequency in the right side, relative frequency in the left and the bars with counts
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

table(x2) %>% 
  tidy() %>%
  mutate(rel_freq = Freq/sum(Freq), sum = sum(Freq)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(x2, Freq), rel_freq)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*length(x2)))
```

[image]

Comment: I made a mistake, in fact, I want to put the cumulative frequency in the right side and draw a line from left to right and put a legend of bar colours and line

Comment: You should probably ask a new question, clarifying what you are looking for with a minimal reproducible example.